# If I specify three values for grid-auto-rows, does CSS create three rows?

Tags: css, css-grid

Say I have the property set:

```
div {
    display: grid
    grid-auto-rows: 15% 70% 15%;
}
```

does this mean that in the container, there will be three rows with the percentages of the parent container as height?

Answer (score 1):

No. `grid-auto-rows` controls the height of *implicit* rows, which are rows created by the grid to place items falling outside the *explicit* grid. `grid-auto-rows`, unlike `grid-template-rows`, does not automatically create rows.

https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#implicit-grids

---

<s>Yes, your `grid-template-rows` rule will create a grid with three explicit rows.</s>

No, the percentage values of `grid-template-rows` will not be relative to the parent's height. They are relative to the height of the same element (the grid container).

You can test it here: https://jsfiddle.net/2cxw0Lrn/

```css
/* body { height: 100vh; } */

article {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 15% 70% 15%;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  height: 100vh; /* disable and try body height above */
  background-color: gray;
}

section { background-color: lightgreen; }
body    { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<article>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
  <section></section>
</article>
```

This behavior is defined in the spec:

> [**7.2. Explicit Track Sizing: the `grid-template-rows` and
>   `grid-template-columns`
>   properties**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#track-sizing)
>
> ***`<length-percentage>`***
>
> `<percentage>` values are relative to the inline size of the **grid
>   container** in column grid tracks, and the block size of the **grid
>   container** in row grid tracks.

You can visit the spec for the meaning of "inline" and "block" size. But the main point is clear: the values are relative to the grid container.

Comment: When you say, they are relative to the same element, then how is the "original" height of that same element determined? By it's content? Can I define the "original" height of that grid container somehow?

Comment: Click on the spec definition heading I posted above. It goes into more detail.